# Rounding calculated percentage

Tags: jasper-reports, rounding, percentage, bigdecimal

This is the formula I'm using to calculate percentage:

```
(new BigDecimal($V{YRSSN_CountsMeasure}).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) ? "0.0%" :
    (100 * $V{Premium_YesMeasure}.floatValue() / $V{YRSSN_CountsMeasure}.floatValue()) + "%"
```

Works well, except that it doesn't format properly. I want 1 decimal after the point and it brings 7! I've tried to use `#,##0.0` pattern, nut it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What pattern setting have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: What type is YRSSN_CountsMeasure and Premium_YesMeasure?

Comment: Pattern I have this: #,##0.0

Comment: this measure is Long, but i also had it BidDecimal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all variable types are BigDecimal, this should work for you:

```
(new BigDecimal($V{YRSSN_CountsMeasure}).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) ? "0.0%" : ($V{Premium_YesMeasure}.divide($V{YRSSN_CountsMeasure}).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(1)) + "%"
```

Edit: Added missing ( at start.

Comment: doesnt work, i get this error:

Comment: com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 1. Syntax error on token ")", delete this token value = new BigDecimal(((java.lang.Long)variable_YRSSN_CountsMeasure.getValue())).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) ? "0.0%" :

Comment: (((java.lang.Long)variable_Premium_YesMeasure.getValue()).divide(((java.lang.Long)variable_YRSSN_CountsMeasure.getValue())).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).setScale(1)) + "%"; //$JR_EXPR_ID=14$ ^ 1 errors

Comment: variable $V{Premium_YesMeasure} and $V{YRSSN_CountsMeasure} both long,if i make them bigDecimal, i get error

Comment: Edited my answer, missing ( at start. My answer assumes all variables are of type BigDecimal.